# ERROR: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I'm facing an issue while run the given below command on azure powershelll to create an alert ,it was working as anticipated day before yesterday.
though surprised it has stopped working

ERROR

ERROR: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: 
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/09251b4d-e2aa-4e1d-a447-2abef1a761ec/resourcegroups/vmrg/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/my-dep?api-version=2018-05-01

i use the following command on powershell

```
az group deployment create --name my-dep -g vmrg --template-file C:\HM\ARM\VMAlertArm\xyz.json --parameters C:\HM\ARM\VMAlertArm\xyz.parameters.json
```

What am i missing???

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but could you try changing the deployment name?

Comment: I have tried that also, no Success

Comment: I've sorted this issue with help of --debug at end of the powershell command as shown below:                                                                                                az group deployment create --name my-dep -g vmrg --template-file C:\ARM\VMAlertArm\xyz.json --parameters C:\ARM\VMAlertArm\xyz.parameters.json --debug

An above statements bring each minute details ,which will be ease to identify the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try appending "--debug"  param at the end of your cli command to enable debug log so that you can see the detailed error message. For instance :

```
az group show --name 'abc'  --debug
```

And we can find underlying http request log and detailed error messages :

[image]

Hope it helps .

Comment: Hello, may I know is it helpful ?

Comment: az group deployment create --name my-dep -g vmrg --template-file C:\ARM\VMAlertArm\xyz.json --parameters C:\ARM\VMAlertArm\xyz.parameters.json --debug

An above statements bring each minute details ,which will be ease to identify the issue